# Sorts RoundingMode and (_ BitVec 3) are incompatible

Tags: z3

In my program this exception is raised when I call z3::solver.push(), when I std::cout the solver before that statement, I get:

```
(declare-fun lv_f_0 () (_ FloatingPoint 8 24))
(assert true)
(assert (fp.eq (fp.mul roundNearestTiesToEven
           lv_f_0
           (fp #b0 #x69 #b00000000000000000000000))
(fp #b0 #x01 #b00000000000000000000000)))
```

But if I check-sat using the binary, it will not throw any exception, and if I write a test program that will produce the above formula, the exception does not occur either. How could I debug the real reason for this problem, since my original program is complex.

**update**
The bug will be trigged if set MODEL to true and set PROOF to true

Comment: That looks like a bug, can you submit a new issue in the issue tracker on github? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Ok, I submit in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/251